# Php pagination for basic cms

Tags: php, pdo, pagination

I have a problem with pagination and I have to admit I am a newbie for programming in php .
I hope,you can tell me how to do pagination for those codes.
index.php , homepage function.

```
function homepage() {
  $results = array();
  $data = Article::getList( HOMEPAGE_NUM_ARTICLES );
  $results['articles'] = $data['results'];
  $results['totalRows'] = $data['totalRows'];
  $results['pageTitle'] = "Widget News";
  require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/homepage.php" );
}
```

Article.php get article function

```
public static function getList( $numRows=1000000, $order="publicationDate DESC" ) {
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS<br> publicationDate FROM articles
            ORDER BY " .$order. " LIMIT :numRows";

 $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
  $st->bindValue( ":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT );
  $st->execute();
  $list = array();

    while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
      $article = new Article( $row );
      $list[] = $article;
    }
```

index.php show article foreach

```
<?php foreach ($results['articles'] as $article){?>
<li>
<h2>
<span class="pubDate"><?php echo date('j F',$article->publicationDate)?></span>
<a href=".?action=viewArticle&amp;articleId=<?php echo $article->id?>">
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($article->title)?>
</a>
</h2>
<p class="summary"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($article->summary)?></p>
</li>
<?php }?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `OFFSET` in MySql string.

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
$itemsPerPage = 10;
$offset = ($page * $itemsPerPage) - $itemsPerPage;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles OFFSET {$offset} LIMIT {$itemsPerPage}";
```

Also remove `<br>` from your code. It's only valid for HTML, elsewhere it will throw error.

---

Final function (start) would look like this:

```
public static function getList($numRows = 10, $order = "publicationDate DESC") {
$conn = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
$order = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z\s]/", '', $order);
$numRows = intval($numROws);
$offset = ($page * $numRows) - $numRows;
$sql = "SELECT
          SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *,
          UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`publicationDate`) AS 'publicationDate'
       FROM `articles`
       ORDER BY {$order}
       LIMIT :numRows
       OFFSET :offset";

$st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
$st->execute(array(':numRows' => $numRows, ':offset' => $pffset));
```

Comment: I have removed `<br>` , How can I update my code with yours ? Also how can i do pagination like 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: @AlpÖzkan pagination is just link with different `&page=#` parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your effort,you have solved my problem